# Canvas tag is not working in Webmatrix

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webmatrix

I was trying to execute this code in `webmatrix`. But don't know why I'm not getting result. I'm getting original image but not in canvas. Also I'm new to `webmatrix`.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <p>Image to use:</p>
        <img id="scream" src="happy.png" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
        <p>Canvas</p>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
        <script>
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("scream");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem concerning the Web Pages framework and WebMatrix, but the Canvas API.

Before to instantiate the drawImage() method the code must wait that the image is loaded. You can accomplish this by using the onload property of the image object as in the example that follows:

```
<script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("scream");
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        }
</script>
```